# Showing that maxima and minima does not exist for this function .

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have a function $f(x) = x^3$ where x $\in(-2,2)$ , so if one asks to tell whether the function has any maximma or minima i would think of saying it has both at its end points but as the endpoints are not contained in the interval so maxima and minima is not reached ? That is there is no maxima/minima at all ?

> I was trying to give a formal proof to it by saying lets say $m$ be the minimum in that open interval attained at some $x= x_0$ , so we have $f(x) \geq m$ , but now how do we show by contradiction that this is not possible ? Similarily for maxima ?

Comment: It seems you're asking about functions rather than series. It's not true that a bounded function must converge to a limit, if that's what you're asking: consider $A(x) = 2+\sin x$ for example.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Do you mean "series"?  Maybe you meant "function", or "sequence"?  In any case, being bounded is not the same as converging.

Comment: Yeah exactly that @GregMartin .thanks but can you also give a proof of why in open interval in case of f(x)= x for x >0  we dont have minima at all ?

Comment: Yeah sorry @lulu i actually was framing this keeping in mind the function behaviour . But yeah i will edit it with function tag too

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Voting to close the question.  As stated, it is hard to guess what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clairty.

Comment: I will ask a better problem : editing

Answer (score 0):

Simple, assume $c$ is the minimum of $f$ on $(-2,2)$. Then $f(c) \le f(x)$,  $\forall x \in (-2,2)$. If $c = 0$, then you can take $x = -1$, then $f(-1) = -1 < 0 = f(0)$. Thus $c \neq 0$. If $c < 0$, then take $x = \dfrac{-2+c}{2}$, then $f\left(\dfrac{-2+c}{2}\right) = \dfrac{(-2+c)^3}{8} < c^3 = f(c) $. This is true since if you have $m < n \implies m^3 < n^3$. Thus $c$ is not a minimum. Similarly for $c > 0$, it is not a minimum. The same can be shown for the case of maximum. Note that the reason for $f$ not having a minimum or a maximum because the interval $(-2,2)$ is not closed. So if you have the interval $[-2,2]$ then $f$ considered above has both a minimum and a maximum due to $f$ being continuous function on the closed interval hence achieving a minimum and maximum on that same interval.